# My helloworld program is not working when i reopen it in Jcreator

Tags: java, jcreator

When i create a new class file , or a new project and then a class file, my HelloWorld program always works. It compiles and runs printing the expected result "Hello world"

Then if i close my Jcreator program and double click on my helloworld program to open it again on Jcreator and try to run it instead of getting the same results i get this:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
          (to execute a class)
    or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
-client   to select the "client" VM
-server   to select the "server" VM
-hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
              The default VM is client.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.

Can you please explain me why is this happening ?
Its embarrassing not be able to make this work.

Thanks.

PS. there is nothing wrong in my code , i get no errors when i compile the file

Comment: Please describe **exactly** what you mean by "and double click on my helloworld program". You cannont click on a "program". Is it a filename in a file browser? Which one? Or what?

Comment: i double clicked my file called "HelloWorld.java" and tried to run it again , and instead of printing the HelloWorld text i got the message above.

Comment: This is the Java Source file. These files cannot be executed. Open that file in JCreator and execute it from there. It will compile that source code first and run the resulting byte code.

Comment: There you are: this is a source program file i.e. a text file which cannot be executed by double-clicking on it. You'll have to create a class file, which is the byte code the java compiler produces from a source file. Maybe Jcreator produces that file - I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Well thats not working either. On Jcreator i just clicked File-Open-HelloWorld ( my java file ) and clicked run , and i got the same message. Jcreator when i execute the HelloWorld program for the first time it creates another file which is the Class file. so I have 2 files, the HelloWorld.java and the HelloWorld.class

Comment: If there is a compiled `helloworld` file. @user3604922 Have you tried to open the whole project, instead of the single class file?

Comment: hmmm, but this isnt right tho. i was using jcreator for all my java projects when i was in the university without using the cmd prompt , and i know about programming, but i cant understand why this is happening now. I havent used programming for 2 years and i forgot what i have to do to run the java files. All the turotials just show you how to create the new java file and write the program and i do that and its working. But when i close the program and re-open the file to run the program again , it just doesnt print the hello world text :/

Comment: @Tom i tried that now and worked. Now i will check which of those files are necessary to load or not everytime. Thanks for the help guys !!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are only using a single class file to run. Since that cannot be executed directly, what you need to do when you finish the program is to **EXPORT THE ENTIRE FILE**. That is what you can use to run, not just a single class.

Comment: Try to explain how the OP has to export, as it looks like he doesn't know why and how.

Comment: Am i not supposed to create a workspace and then a project tha belongs to that workspace and then create my classes ? And then do like @Tom said by opening all the classes in Jcreator to make it run ? Although i do remember in the past that by opening one single file ( the one that has the public static void main) you could execute all the others.

Comment: @PsyCode A HelloWorld-type of program can be run with java <classname> if the class file containing that class is in the working directory. No need to export anything.